# Email validation in visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, email

I have created a visualforce page where the chatter functionality will be given access to the external members of an organisation by entering an external agency email address. I have put validations to check the contents of the email field. For example if I have put email address as abc it throws an error as "enter email address in the correct format". But if I try to save the email address as blank space it gets saved and a blank space user is shown in the pending list of members.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a snippet of your code to help us understand how you have built the page. I can imagine one possibility of what might be causing this problem, but it would be easier if I knew what your VF page contained. Also, it would help to know what the underlying datatype of the field was. Typically, with Force.com, you shouldn't have to validate email entries if your field is the correct data type.

Comment: Agreed, the regex to check if an email is valid is actually fairly enormous: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. So you should just bind your vf input to an email field and have sf do it for you.

Comment: To follow on from grigriforce's comment and the related link, I've come to the conclusion that the only real validation that you should perform on email address fields is that they contain an "@" and perhaps get a user to enter twice to reduce mis-spellings. Anything else is almost certainly guaranteed to not be correct unless you do the insane RFC922 validation which honestly is only slightly better than testing for "@".

Comment: Ohk.Let me first explain you the scenario,in the vf page there are two sets of objects, one is internal members of the organisation and another external members given chatter access through email invite....so I cannot make the external email field mandatory!! The second one is creating the problem...

Comment: Here is the code snippet...let me know if any changes are needed in th code!!
public string setEmailAdd {get;set;}
  
public static String validEmailOrBlank(String setEmailAdd)
{
if (setEmailAdd != null || setEmailAdd='' )
system.debug('Enter a email ADDRESS'+setEmailAdd);
String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)....Regex & Email validations!!
system.debug('Enter a email Address'+setEmailAdd);
    if (!emailMatcher.matches()) {
        setEmailAdd = '';
    }
   
    }
    else
    return null;
    return setEmailAdd; 
}

Comment: Its a bit long...so giving the code in two comments...

Comment: private List<User> isExistingExternalUser() {
             System.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^Ext email id^^^^^^^'+setEmailAdd);
            List<User> userList = [SELECT Id,IsActive FROM User WHERE email=:setEmailAdd AND ProfileId=:chatterExternalProfile.Id];
            system.debug('isExistingExternalUser: '+userList );
            
            return userList ; 
            }

Answer (score 1):

For that also you need to keep a condition

say Suppose

```
var email = $(".email").val();
if(email=='' || email==null){
    alert("Enter a email Address");
    $(".email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

If u put a condition like that then it will throw a error message

Comment: adding &nbsp will work ??

Comment: no.You have to keep a condition for it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apex:inputText component, you can use the "required" attribute to make it mandatory to a user to enter a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apex input text you can use the below apex code using regular expressions

```
public static boolean isUserEmailValid(String userEmail) {
        Boolean flag = false;
        if(userEmail != null) {
            String  emailRegex      = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})';
            Pattern emailPattern    = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
            Matcher emailMatcher    = emailPattern.matcher(userEmail.trim());
            flag                    =  emailMatcher.matches();
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with the code...but the problem still remains.Its taking spaces!!

Comment: Before passing value to this code please check that the given value is not null and empty and then pass to it

Comment: FYI, this regex is suitable for situations where users are expected to have "normal" email addresses, but there are many many email addresses that are valid that will fail against this regex. See the link that grigriforce posted for the RFC-compliant regex for validating email addresses. I don't recommend using regexes for email address validation.